# Remove index.php from codeigniter in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

My codeigniter is installed in admin_new folder on hostinger and path of installed codeigniter is **public_html/vishwa/admin_new/** and i am trying to remove index.php from url.

I have changed my .htaccess file as below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /vishwa/admin_new/
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have checked forums and it says mode_rewrite is enabled as default on hostinger. but it is showing error like **No input file specified**.

I have also changed config settings in config.php as below:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

but still it is showing same error. Why this type of error has been shown and how can i solve it.

Comment: Have you set base_config to `http://www.yourdomain.tld/vishwa/admin_new/`? Also change this in `.htaccess` file `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]` (note the question mark).

Comment: great. It removed the error. but when i got to url http://gurukrupa.tk/vishwa/admin_new/users it shows the http://gurukrupa.tk/vishwa/admin_new/users url in address baar. and other thing is it is not loading the css also.

Comment: Ok. When i removed '?' after admin_new it works fine.

Comment: Probably you are using relative paths and that way it depends on uri segments count. For css you should use something like `<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css'); ?>`. For JS files and images too.

Comment: got it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Enjoy your code. #SOreadytohelp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```