# Remove index.php in code igniter for subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have some problem. In development I'm using php 7 and my website work well. But in production it using php 5.4 and I have problem in removing index.php. My website hosted in subfolder just like `myhost/mywebsitefolder`.

The problem is when using url function. example, when I accesing 'dashboard' page it will redirect to 'login' page and the url is like `myhost/mywebsitefolder/login` and it return 404 page not found. When I add index.php before login (`myhost/mywebsitefolder/index.php/login`) it work well but I must replace all of my url by adding index.php. Are there any solution. My .htaccess is just like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mywebsitefolder/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|gallery|json|slider|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Try with adding question mark in line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`.

Answer (score 3):

Try with a slash before the dots, like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /mywebsitefolder
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|gallery|json|slider|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

And in *application/config/config.php* and clear the index page config value:

```
// Old
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";

// New
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Sometimes you need to enable it the rewrite module, run "apache2 enable module rewrite":

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

You need to restart the webserver to apply the changes:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope it works!

If no, there is others threads with the same problem,you can take a look:
- [Remove index.php from codeigniter in subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449020/remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-in-subfolder)
- [Remove index.php from Codeigniter URL in subfolder with Wordpress in root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943040/remove-index-php-from-codeigniter-url-in-subfolder-with-wordpress-in-root)
- [Using htaccess to remove codeigniter index.php in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765883/using-htaccess-to-remove-codeigniter-index-php-in-a-subdirectory)

Comment: Thanks, the problem is in my apache module I think